# Components of a vector

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

If I have the angle between two vectors, and I have the components $(x,y,z)$ 
of the first vector $( xi + yj + zk)$, how can I know the components $(x',y',z')$ of the second vector ?

Answer (score 1):

Set of all the values of x, y, z satisfying following equation is your solution,

since, $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{v\cdot u}{|v|\cdot|u|}$

$\cos\alpha=\dfrac{xx_1+yy_1+zz_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}$

Comment: I have The angle (a) and (x,y,z ) I want the (x1,y1,z1) and I know that both of them in the same plane

Comment: do you know in which plane they are?

Comment: both of the vectors are in plane z

Comment: Plane z? a plane is formed by combination of two axes like xy, xz or yz. btw Plane z also means complex plane.

Comment: http://www.starkeffects.com/images/refraction-vectors.png

Answer (score 0):

Taketheir dot product then all values of $x$, $y$, $z$ satisfying resulting equation is your answer.

Comment: if I know that both of them in the same plane can I know the components ? or not ?